# Is it possible to program bluetooth streaming on Android from one device to several devices in parallel?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I am trying to figure out if there is an abilily to program on android a music streaming through Bluetooth connection. However, I want to manage it from one phone device to several phone devices in parallel.
So far, I have managed to create a connection but not streaming.

Answer (score 0):

Streaming is possible from phone to pc speaker. Not sure whether you can run in  parallel or not.

Comment: thanks, but i'm talking about establishing a connection between phones.

Answer (score 0):

This app could do the trick:

Bluetooth Music Player Free

You need to install it on both Android devices and pair them. 
Since they are doing it so programatically it is possible.

Comment: You should look at AirAudio also

Comment: thanks again, but that app(bluetooth media player) dosent work correct and  probably do not support a connection between several devices.